# How can i use Ajax success data in same template or somewhere else?

Tags: python, html, ajax, django-templates

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'my_url' %}",
        async: false,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            name = data.name
        error: function(e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });
```

Here i want to use this name variable in template(In Django Template). How can i use directly?
Means can i use like

```
<html>
{% if myname = = name %}
<input type="text" value="name" disable</input>
{%endif%}
</html>
```

Here name is a variable coming from django views in ajax success.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask: AJAX is client side logic, but there are no templates on the client side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User your ajax response like this

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'my_url' %}",
            async: false,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
                name = data.name
            $("#anyID").val(name); // like you can populate the values using id or class
            error: function(e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: how can i access name in a condition?? Here I can only populate but is there any way where i can use name in condition( In Template) i.e {% if name = =name %} <a>Hi I am In condition</a>{%endif%)